# What does NetMapOperator do?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Recently, I have become addicted to Mathematica's support for neural networks. As I learn those commands that are prefixed with "Net", I can't tell the difference between using `NetMapOperator`, and not using it. For example,

[image]

From the help information, I just think that this command only serves to normalize the input and output formats. Can anyone point out its substantive functions?

Comment: Please make sure to include your code as text, rather than as images.

Comment: I will pay attention next time. @MarcoB

Answer (score 6):

```
NetChain[
 {
  LinearLayer[3]
  },
 "Input" -> 2
 ]
```

[image]

```
NetChain[
 {
  NetMapOperator[LinearLayer[3]]
  },
 "Input" -> 2
 ]
```

[image]

In the first network `LinearLinear` is applying to the whole input sequence and output has size 3.

In the second network `LinearLinear` is applying to the every element of sequence and output has size 2*3. This is the same as [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) in Keras.

In your examples `try1` was evaluated on the batch of data (batch = 4, size of the data point = 2) and `try2` was evaluated on the single data point with dimension {4,2}.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think I understand. `try1` is just like a function with Listable attribute. `try2` is just like a function map on a list. So, the results is the same!